# Does javascript supports conversion of integer X to X.0 as typeof number?

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, precision

Given string lets say “5”
I want to convert it to 5.0 (typeof Number).

Already tried combinations/permutations of all the following:

```
parseFloat()
toFixed()
toPrecision()
Number()
```

Also tried with “+” (implicit Number casting)

I always end up with either typeof string. Or just the number 5.

[image]

Its for an API that expects “float” but does not accept integers (5 is invalid, 5.0 is valid).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: The number 5 is equal to 5.0. Are you instead talking about hope it’s *displayed*? That’s a separate concern.

Comment: `5.0===5 //true`. that api, how is it accessed? internally in the webpage? over a network request?

Comment: How are you sending the data to the external API? Can you post an example of sending a `float` which works?

Comment: I need to send it to external API (trough network post request) and when I tested it in Postman, it accepts 5.0 but not 5.

I send post request with json obj: {value:5} and it returns invalid but if I send {value:5.0} its valid.

I am aware that 5===5.0 yet the external API has validation that the number has at least one number after the decimal point (I don't know how the external API is implemented, its just based on the return error of "value should be float")

Comment: Could you provide a link to the API documentation?

Comment: That's a horrible API. Are you sure it's JSON? `{value: 5}` is an object literal, `{"value": 5}` is a JSON document. I would report this as a bug, not try to find a workaround that makes `JSON.stringify` add `.0` to integer numbers.

Comment: I tried the workaround with stringify but it doesn’t work, ill try to reach put to the API…

Comment: @nirjacob "*I tried the workaround with stringify*" - what exactly have you tried? You still didn't show us how you make the HTTP request. Please [edit] your question to add that code. But yes, definitely try everything to get that API fixed…